# pem.Decode - returns nil when given contents of id_rsa.pem

Tags: encryption, go, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to use `rsa` package for `encrypt` and `decrypt` with `public` and `private` keys.

```
func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    text := "my super secret"
    glog.Infof("Original text: %s\n", text)

    glog.Infoln("Loading public key..")
    pubKey, err := loadPublicKey("id_rsa.pub")
    if err == nil {
        glog.Infoln("SUCCESS!")
    } else {
        glog.Errorln("LOOSE =(")
    }

    etext, err := encrypt([]byte(text), pubKey)
    if err != nil {
        glog.Errorf("Can't encrypt text: %+v\n", err)
    }
    glog.Infof("Encrypted text: %s\n", etext)

    glog.Infoln("Loading private key..")
    privKey, err := loadPrivateKey("id_rsa")
    if err == nil {
        glog.Infoln("SUCCESS!")
    } else {
        glog.Errorln("LOOSE =(")
    }

    dtext, err := decrypt(etext, privKey)
    if err != nil {
        glog.Errorf("Can't decrypt text: %+v\n", err)
    }
    glog.Infof("Decrypted text: %s\n", dtext)

    glog.Flush()
}

func loadPublicKey(path string) (*rsa.PublicKey, error) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    block, _ := pem.Decode(data)
    if block == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("no key found\n")
    }

    if block.Type != "PUBLIC KEY" {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid key type - %s\n", block.Type)
    }

    pubKey, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("can't parse key - %+v\n", err)
    }

    return pubKey.(*rsa.PublicKey), nil
}

func loadPrivateKey(path string) (*rsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    block, _ := pem.Decode(data)
    if block == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("no key found\n")
    }

    if block.Type != "PRIVATE KEY" {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid key type - %s\n", block.Type)
    }

    return x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
}

func encrypt(data []byte, pubKey *rsa.PublicKey) ([]byte, error) {
    return rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, pubKey, data)
}

func decrypt(data []byte, privKey *rsa.PrivateKey) ([]byte, error) {
    return rsa.DecryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, privKey, data)
}
```

But I have an error in `rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15`:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x5c16c]

goroutine 1 [running]:
crypto/rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(0x11641f8, 0xc8200762a0, 0x0, 0xc82004ddc8, 0xf, 0x20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/rsa/pkcs1v15.go:32 +0x5c
main.encrypt(0xc82004ddc8, 0xf, 0x20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/cnaize/Dropbox/develop/gocode/src/test/main.go:132 +0x87
main.main()
    /Users/cnaize/Dropbox/develop/gocode/src/test/main.go:67 +0x3b8
```

Why where is the error? How to resolve this?

**EDITED**:

thanks, now I understand the problem - in `loadPublicKey("id_rsa.pub")` `pem.Decode(data)` returns `nil block`.

What is the right way to parse `ssh` keys?

Comment: Please edit with the full output of the error (stack trace included). Also you should definitely be handling the error returned by EncryptPKCS1v15 (not the source of the problem but it'll be a source of future problems).

Comment: @voutasaurus `pem.Decode` doesn't provide any errors, it just returns `nil block`

Comment: Oh, right. So your data is probably incorrect. Put in a log.Println(data) and see whether it matches your file. If it does then the file itself is not in pem format. Check the file has the PEM header/footer (i.e. the BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE thing).

Comment: Also as an aside I recommend just using log instead of glog (tutorial: http://www.goinggo.net/2013/11/using-log-package-in-go.html).

Comment: Does the ssh key stored in id_rsa actually work otherwise? Also is it password protected?

Comment: @voutasaurus yes, the public key must to be valid, because I use it on github for example, it starts with `ssh-rsa`, is it ok? and yes, it password protected. how to parse it correctly?

Comment: Take a look at the x509 package. https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#DecryptPEMBlock

FYI the public key is probably not encrypted. But the password will be required if you want to read the private key.

Comment: Given that it's a public key that you're trying to read, would you consider posting it here?

Comment: @voutasaurus nevermind, after generating key-pair with `openssl`, everything works, thanks for your help